# Como puedo hacer para que los enemigos solo salgan desde los bordes de la pantalla? JS - PHASER3

Tags: javascript, phaser3

Estoy haciendo un pequeno juego, estoy implementando un ememigo que sale aleatoriamente y persigue al jugador, el problema es que yo quiero que salga desde los bordes solamente, es decir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para eso lo hago de esta forma:

```
createexplosiveEnemy() {
    let positionX = Phaser.Math.Between(-33,globalThis.config.width);
    let positionY = 2;
    let explosive_enemy = this.scene.physics.add.sprite(positionX,positionY,"enemy");
    explosive_enemy.setSize(10,10); //size of the collider box
    this.scene.explosive_enemy_group.add(explosive_enemy);
}
```

de esta forma el enemigo solamente me sale desde el borde superior, ya que Y esta declarado como 2 y X desde -33 hasta la longitud de la pantalla, el  problema es con los otros bordes, ya que si asigno a Y una altura random, el enemigo puede salir tambien en el medio de la pantalla, ya que cumple con dichas coordenas, es decir: Y = 300 X = 300, quedando asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo solo quiero que salga desde los bordes, pero no se me ocurre como, agrego que aqui que la coordenada Y es al reves, es decir negativo hacia arriba y positivo hacia abajo, X si esta bien

Answer (score 0):

Puedes generar un valor al azar para saber desde dónde debe aparecer el enemigo:

1. Desde arriba (Y negativo)
2. Desde abajo (Y positivo, mayor a la altura del contenedor)
3. Desde la izquierda (X negativo)
4. Desde la derecha (X positivo, mayor a la anchura del contenedor)

En los casos de 1 y 2, X es al azar
En los casos 3 y 4, Y es al azar

```
createexplosiveEnemy() {
    let PositionX = 0;
    let PositionY = 0;
    let fromStart = Phaser.Math.Between(1, 4);
    // Arriba o abajo
    if(fromStart == 1 || fromStart == 2) {
        // Si es desde arriba, valor negativo
        // Si es desde abajo, con la altura del contenedor
        PositionY = (fromStart == 1) ? -33 : globalThis.config.height;
        PositionX = Phaser.Math.Between(-33,globalThis.config.width);
    } else {
        // Si es desde izquierda, valor negativo
        // Si es desde derecha, con el ancho del contenedor
        PositionX = (fromStart == 3) ? -33 : globalThis.config.width;
        PositionY = Phaser.Math.Between(-33,globalThis.config.height);;
    }

    let explosive_enemy = this.scene.physics.add.sprite(positionX,positionY,"enemy");
    explosive_enemy.setSize(10,10); //size of the collider box
    this.scene.explosive_enemy_group.add(explosive_enemy);
}
```

Con esto estás forzando a que el enemigo aparezca fuera de los límites de la pantalla y desde cualquier dirección.